# file.exe has stopped working when opening very large file

Tags: file, input, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    ifstream input("numbers.txt");
    int a[500000];

    if (input.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 499999; i = i + 50000)
        {
            input >> a[i];
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Could not open File" << endl << endl;
}
```

The file name "numbers.txt" is a simple txt file that contains exactly 500,000 integer numbers. Testing this code out on a small file of 100 integers it worked fine, but whenever I read this file is gave me the usual "file.exe has stopped working". Any idea why?

Comment: Why do you have `i = i + 50000`? Why not `i++`?

Comment: I'm doing a small test sample so that I can see if it's working instead of seeing all 500,000. That allows it to only show 10 numbers.